# nginx convert filepath as query string if file does not exist

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am writing a rewrite rule for below scenario, want to the rule to work if the file does not exist

> from:
>   /news/press_releases/2016/12/filenews.html
>
> to:
>   /news/news-details.php?newsYear=2016&newsMonth=12&newsID=filenews

rewrite rule:

> location ~ /news/press_release {
>
> rewrite ^/news/press_releases/([1-9][0-9]*)/([1-9][0-9]*)/(.*).html$
>   https://www.example.com/news/news-details.php?newsYear=$1&newsMonth=$2&newsID=$3;
>   }

the above rewrite rule works but i want the rewrite rule to work if the file does not exist (.html) tried the try_file but no luck any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~ /news/press_release/(?<year>\d{4})/(?<month>\d{2})/(?<title>.+)\.html {
    try_files /news/press_release/$year/$month/$title.html /news/news-details.php?newsYear=$year&newsMonth=$month&newsID=$title;
}
```

The trick here is to capture the details of the article in the `location` directive, and then use the captured information in the `try_files` directive.

I used named capture groups for clarity in the regex capture.

Comment: error while reloading nginx 
pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "/news/press_release/(?<year>\d" in /etc/nginx/vhosts.d/

Comment: My regex pattern was missing one `)` character, I fixed it now.

Comment: forgot to mention i tried adding that also still there is error

* Checking nginx' configuration ...nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "/news/press_release/(?<year>\d" in /etc/nginx/vhosts.d/abc_dir.include:305
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "/news/press_release/(?<year>\d" in /etc/nginx/vhosts.d/abc.include:305
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: should the regex in location be in quotes ? and the ^ in the beginning and $ in the end of the string be included ?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

> location ^~ /news/ {
>
> try_files $uri @rule1;}
>
> location @rule1 {
>
> rewrite ^/news/press_releases/([1-9][0-9]*)/([1-9][0-9]*)/(.*).html$
>   /news/news-details.php?newsYear=$1&newsMonth=$2&newsID=$3; }